# Debian TFTP installer loading very slow

Tags: debian, tftp

at our facility we use TFTP to allow diskless boot of our workstations, everything is fast and good :)

Now I'm prepraing to install Debian to muliple workstations, so I decided TFTP. I setup one test workstation, and modified DHCP:

```
host kmwil-deb1 {
            next-server IP_ADDRESS;
            filename "/kmwil/jessie/pxelinux.0";
            hardware ethernet aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa;
            fixed-address kmwil-deb1;
}
```

I downloaded [Debian netboot installer](http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) and unpacked archive to the proper directory (file is accessible, `chown` to `tftp`, etc.).

PROBLEM: It takes about 5 minutes to see the Debian installer main screen. Machine gets address from DHCP, then `TFPT..` shows, then `PXELINUX Peter Anvin bla bla`. This step takes about 5 minutes. I `grep` logs, this is the result.

[TFTP download log](http://duch.mimuw.edu.pl/~kmwil/kmwil_debian_tftp.log)

I tried `curl` the Debian archive from my `tftp` location and it took 15 seconds.

EDIT: 18:38

I read apropriate RFC and got `tcpdump` communication :)
I observed multiple RRQ (Read Requests) for one file from client PC, from different ports. All of them were ACK. It looks like simultaneous RRQs?
I also observed about 5 sec. timeouts between multiple RRQ and ACK from server. Don't know the reason for this yet.

I also setup virtual network with two hosts (Virtualbox), one as DHCP and TFTP server, second as pure client. Here installer loading is instantaneous.
`tcpdump` is "clean", only one RRQ from single port, one ACK and no timeouts.

Best Regards,
Kamil

Comment: did you know that, depending on the pxe software you use, you can use http rather than tftp to boot the debian installer?  that's what i do on my pxe/tftp server.  tftpd to serve just `ipxe` and then http from then on.  http://ipxe.org/

Answer (score 0):

5 seconds sounds like a DNS timeout. Maybe your TFTP server insists on resolving the IP address of the incoming requests, but the first name server in its `/etc/resolv.conf` does not answer to such requests? A full `tcpdump` trace of the server traffic could help.